# A generic error occurred in GDI+ at System.Drawing.Image.Save (file being used by another process)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a web project in ASP.Net, C#.
I am uploading an image, saving it, then creating a thumbnail and saving that. It works the first time, but if I try and upload the same image again, I get the "A generic error occurred in GDI+" error on the **thumbnail** save (the full image is ok).
I have tried to delete the thumbnail in FTP but this gives the error "550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. " 
snippet of code below

```cs
System.Drawing.Image thumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight,
                                new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback),
                                IntPtr.Zero );
img.Dispose();

// crop
System.Drawing.Image cropped_thumb = Crop(thumb, Size, Size, AnchorPosition.Center);

EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long)80);
ImageCodecInfo ici = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

cropped_thumb.Save(ImageTo, ici, ep);   // error here
cropped_thumb.Dispose();
```

(note: ImageTo is a string)

Here is the ASP code showing the image:

```
    <a href="<%# DetailRef(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title"),         
    DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Details")) %>">
        <asp:image ImageURL =   
    <%#Thumbnail(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Artist"),
    DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Title")) %>
    runat="server" id="lblworkimg" width=270 />
```

and here is the c# code:

```
    public string Thumbnail(object pArtist, object pTitle)
    {
        string thumbDir =    
    (string)ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ThumbFolder"];
        thumbDir = thumbDir + (string)pArtist + "\\";
    return thumbDir + Utils.ToFileName((string)pTitle) + ".jpg";
    }
```

[note: ToFileName simply removes all illegal characters from the string, like ":", "?" etc ]

Comment: Do you have something that is loading and showing the `ImageTo` file? This code alone won't replicate the problem.

Comment: To note that `System.Drawing` is not exactly well supported server-side.

Comment: it's perfectly possible that another browser could be viewing the ImageTo file - but surely that would open it read-only and not lock it?

Comment: `but surely that would open it read-only and not lock it?`  Don't assume that, and don't call me Shirley.

Comment: but if that were the case then many people would have come across this problem already wouldn't they, Shirley?

Comment: Jimi, I've edited the original post to include the code showing the image

Comment: Why is `cropped_thumb` disposed but `thumb` isn't? We can't tell from your code but it seems highly likely that you're leaking objects that are holding a file handle open.

Comment: Thanks Damien, good point (which I will correct), but would that really cause this problem?